# Materialize slider deorganised my images size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

i'm new here and also new at coding, i have been practicing with Visual Studio Code for a week now and i come with the following problem: i'm making a Slider with content inside so i can edit it and put a button inside it with a modal, i manage to make it work but as soon as i made it the images on the info cards for some reason went out of the limits of the info card, i can't figure out what i did wrong. this is my code and i apologize if this is not the correct way of uploading a code i still don't know how to properly use the site correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!----------------------------------------Zona de Extensiones+6------------------------------------------>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Prueba numero2/assets/css/style3.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Prueba numero2/assets/materialize/css/materialize.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<style>

.slider .indicators .indicator-item {
  background-color: #666666 !important;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
}
.slider .indicators .indicator-item.active {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
.slider {
  width: 900px !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.slider .indicators {
  bottom: 60px !important;
  z-index: 100 !important;
  /* text-align: left; */
}

nav {
background-color: black !important;
border-style: outset white 100px !important;

}
.carousel-inner img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.nav-wrapper .brand-logo .logo {
width: 64px !important;
}
html {
box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit !important;
}

.column {
float: left !important;
width: 33.3% !important;
margin-bottom: 16px !important;
padding: 0 8px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
.column {
width: 100% !important;
display: block !important;
}
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 16px !important;
}
.card {
  border-style: outset !important;
  border-color: black 10px !important;
}

.container::after, .row::after {
  content: "" !important;
  clear: both !important;
  display: table !important;
}

.title {
  color: goldenrod !important;
}

.button {
  border: none !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  padding: 8px !important;
  color: white !important;
  background-color: #000 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #555 !important;
}
footer div  {
   max-width: 100% !important;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!----------------------------------------Scrips----------------------------------------->


<!----------------------------------------Scrips----------------------------------------->

<header>
<div class="panel">
<span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; height:100vh;"></span>
<span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; ">
<p class="title">L'excellance</p>
<p class="sub-title" style-color="goldenrod"> V.I.P Suites <a></p>
</div>
</header>

<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
<a href="#" class="brand-logo right"><img class="logo" src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/36814_preview.png"alt="L'excellance"></a>
<ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
<li><a href="sass.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="badges.html"></a></li>
<li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
 <br><br>

<section>
<p>
Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue eratatmassa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum anteipsumprimis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, eliterat euismodorci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus,bibendum sed, posuereac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere.Praesent turpis.
</p>
</section>

<br>
<br>
<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-border-light-grey w3-round w3-padding"></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<div class="card">
<img class="materialboxed" data-caption="CEO & Founder Sugma Joe " src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/65/fc/a065fcc880c5c1b0fdc38c5d42a6f1af.jpg" alt="Jane" style="width:100%">
<div class="container">
<h2>Lorem</h2>
<p class="title">CEO & Founder</p>
<p>Some text that describes me lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.</p>
<p>example@example.com</p>
<p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
<div class="card">
<img class="materialboxed" width="auto" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/65/fc/a065fcc880c5c1b0fdc38c5d42a6f1af.jpg" alt="Mike" style="width:100%">
<div class="container">
<h2>Lorem</h2>
<p class="title">Art Director</p>
<p>Some text that describes me lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.</p>
<p>example@example.com</p>
<p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
<div class="card">
<img class="materialboxed" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/65/fc/a065fcc880c5c1b0fdc38c5d42a6f1af.jpg" alt="John" style="width:100%">
<div class="container">
<h2>Lorem</h2>
<p class="title">Designer</p>
<p>Some text that describes me lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.</p>
<p>example@example.com</p>
<p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="divider"></div>
<br>
<br>
<!----------------------------------------Sección 3------------------------------------------>
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="Prueba numero2/assets/img/Meaning-of-travelling.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption center-align">
        <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="Prueba numero2/assets/img/Meaning-of-travelling.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption left-align">
        <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="Prueba numero2/assets/img/Meaning-of-travelling.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption right-align">
        <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="Prueba numero2/assets/img/Meaning-of-travelling.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption center-align">
        <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<!----------------------------------------Fin de Sección 3------------------------------------------>
<!----------------------------------------footer------------------------------------------>

<!----------------------------------------Zona de Scrips------------------------------------------>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
  });
</script>         


 <script>

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed');
    var instances = M.Materialbox.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
  });
  </script>

<script>
  // init materialize tab
  var elem = $('.tabs')
     var options = {}
     var instance = M.Tabs.init(elem, options);

  //or Without Jquery


    //var elem = document.querySelector('.tabs');
     var options = {}
     var instance = M.Tabs.init(elem, options);
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) please? I tried pasting your code directly there, but many things broke. Also, try to remove unnecessary code to make debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

to post your code here just type your text message then under the message paste your code,
select your code paragraph and then hit ctrl+K, that should set your message to be posted with a code...
post your code for others to be able to help you...

Comment: Thanks a lot for that tip, i manage to edit and add the code without a problem